# How to use CRUD with Interactive 3d model? - Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am new to learn Three.js and I am not sure it's exactly suit for my needs!

I am creating web application using PHP to keep car accident details.

I was wondering if it's possible to have interactive 3d car object and I can mark the damage on the car with mouse click and post to server.(Create,Read,Update,Delete).

So when ever I open the client details I can see the damages that already mark on the car.

Could someone point me the right direction.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have car model and you can write some javascript code to change this car model by mouse clicking. Problem is that you have to learn a lot about Three.js, 3d graphic and javascript. So the right direction is to start learning those 3 things. Three.js is not a 3d modeling tool so if you want to create car models in the browser you will have to write your own 3d modeling code. When you will have this Read, Update and Delete will just work. You will only have to add some code to write changes made in browser to your server.